# How to change the app environment at run time?

Tags: php, laravel

How can I change the app environment at run time?

I have some classes that only bind in the service provider in production. I'd like to assert with a unit test that they are properly bound. For other environment variables, I can set them with the `config` helper and then simply call `resetApplication` in `tearDown` but for some reason the variable set by `APP_ENV` doesn't change.

```
dump(app()->environment()); // "testing"

config(['app.env' => 'production']);

dump(app()->environment()); // "testing"
```

What can I do to get `app()->environment()` to return `production` at run time?

Comment: Do you have ` app.php` with a array key name `env` ?

Comment: Interesting, it seems to [bypass](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L474) the config and read directly from the `.env`. Not sure that there's a straightforward way to do that.

Comment: @C2486 this is setup by the framework. calling `config('app.env')` will return `testing`

Comment: I am not sure what causes it but cant you define another env variable like binding? and check double condtion on your service providers instead of only environment ?
something like `if (\Config::get('binding') == true or \Config::get('environment') == 'production') `

Comment: @AnarBayramov thanks for the possible workaround, but I'd prefer a cleaner approach at this time. :)

Comment: @devk well it doesn't directly read from the `.env` file, it pulls the array index of `env` from the Application class. it's not clear how that's set/modified. unless I'm missing something from that link you shared?

Comment: You could use `app()['env'] = 'production';`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that it does, but it seems to. The `Application` has `$this['env']` and `$this['config']`, I assume they're what the `env()` and `config()` helpers return. The `environment()` reads from the `$this['env']`

Comment: I think you can't change .env file dynamically . Either it has to change file input/output or you can it by laravel by creating another config file . Create one file named `myenv.php` inside config folder and then you can set it like `config (["myenv.env"=>"test"])` where `env` is array key returning from `myenv.php`.

Comment: @Jeemusu that's the solution I was looking for! Please post an answer and I'll mark it accepted :) thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`app()->environment()` reads directly from the variables specified in your .env file rather than the configuration files.

You could take two approaches to solve your problem.

## 1. Read the environment variables from the config file rather than the .env file.

```
dump(config('app.env')); // "testing"

config(['app.env' => 'production']);

dump(config('app.env')); // "production"
```

## 2. Change the value of 'env' in the current app instance by changing the value of `app()['env']`.

```
dump(app()->environment()); // "testing"

app()['env'] = 'production';

dump(app()->environment()); // "production"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that above answer can be a bit dangerous: You might be overwriting the 'env' key, without truly switching environments. Suddenly your app says that you are in testing, while your DB connection is still set to production.

Normally you just want to really stick to the Laravel best practice of defining ONE environment for each literal environment, but for my use case I needed to temporarily & programmatically switch between multiple environments within a single artisan script.

My solution (works in Laravel 5.8+ with DotEnv3) would be to really reboot the application:

```php
<?php

$basepath = app()->basePath();
$env = app()->basePath('.env.alternative');
$boot = app()->basePath('bootstrap/app.php');

// Overwrite webserver env
(new Dotenv($basepath,'.env.alternative'))->overload();

// Reboot the application
(require $boot)
    ->loadEnvironmentFrom($env)
    ->make(Kernel::class)
    ->bootstrap();

// This returns 'mysql_alternative', as defined in .env.alternative
dd(DB::connection()->getName())
```

Disclaimer: I've only tested this to the extend of my own code.

Answer (score 0):

From a testing point of view, then in the setUp() method:

```
$this->app['env'] = 'production';
```

But remember, only do this in a test class, specifically testing production runs. Otherwise, do it at the top of the test method, remembering to set it back to testing at the end.

If you adjust the `setUp()` method, remember your `tearDown()` method and change it to testing. By altering the `$this->app['env']`, you are directly changing the Applications environment, which is why it's so important to remember to set it back as it will produce side effects, also only do this in testing .